# Why (int)(14/13 - 0.001) yield 0 and not 1?

Tags: java, floating-point

Isn't it true that if you cast a float number like `1.0012` to an integer, it will become `1`?

Then why is it when I write:

```
(int)(14/13-0.001)
```

instead of `1.07592` ~ become `1` it becomes `0` ?

(Java compiled with Eclipse).

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: the title of question is not correct, `(int)(1.01 - 0.01)` will produce 1 not 0.

Comment: 14/13 is equal to 1 if they are integers - and they are in your example. Subtracting .01 and then taking the it will produce 0

Comment: [is floating point math broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: In primary school you might have done integer division where something like `14 divided by` 13 is `1 with 1 remainder`.  This is how integer arithmetic works and you can do `14 % 13` to get the remainder.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Thanks for your suggestion, but if you actually take the time to read the question, you will see that the OP is not at the stage where the document you provide a link to is likely to help.

Comment: @PascalCuoq sorry I was not reading carefully at first

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does truncating. For 1.0012 it just removes part on right of decimal point.

In example

```
(int)(14/13-0.001)
```

14/13 will be 1 and then it will be converted to double, 1.0-0.001 = 0.999, and after truncating it becomes 0.

Comment: It will be converted to double, not float.

Comment: If I remember correctly it will be float, but the result will be same nonetheless.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html: *A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.*

Comment: Yep, I think you are right, I checked documentation.

Comment: it's really count 14/13 as interger so i had to write it as (float)14/13-.001

Comment: 14.0/13 or 14/13.0 is enough, shorter and easier to type, no need to cast

Answer (score 8):

`14 / 13` is an integer division. Its value is 1.

`1 - 0.01` is thus lower than 1.

Casting it to int thus yields 0.

Use `14.0 / 13 - 0.001` or `14d / 13 - 0.001` instead.